# Setup an application from a parent application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on an application which acts as a setup box for other child applications. I want to set up child applications from one central parent application. Set up includes database setup (db:create and db:migrate), subdomain set up etc for child apps.

This is going to work like this: a Subscriber will subscribe many applications. On subscription the application will be configured to work on subscribers provided subdomain (on my site). Every instance of a subscribed application will have its own database. So I need to set up database for each subscriber, and domain name too.

Currently I am creating database based on child application subdomain, using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`.
After creation of the database I want to load the schema of the child app to the database created. For this I had posted a question here
[schema.sql not creating even after setting schema_format = :sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698467/schema-sql-not-creating-even-after-setting-schema-format-sql)

Is there any good efficient method/approach that will help me?
Also I am a bit confused about subdomaining how its gonna be work?

Any help/thought appreciated...

Thanks,
Pravin

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no real need for a separate database for each user and for each 'app', you may want to check out a term called multi tenant.

Also, subdomains can be handled in rails 3 and use something called Devise for User authentication.  Github has a [rails 3 sudomain devise authentication](https://github.com/fortuity/rails3-subdomain-devise) fork to get you started.

Until you really see a need for all these databases, keep it simple. One database per application, and connect to each application via Active Resource.

Be warned, that what you are undertaking can confuse even a hardened app builder, so i hope your experience begets that of which your current Stackoverflow rate is at.

All the best.