# schema.rb index different from individual migration index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have this for my migration:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.integer :parent_id
      t.string  :title, :null => false
    end
    execute('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_categories_root_title ON categories (title) WHERE parent_id IS NULL') 
  end
  def down
    drop_table :categories
  end
end
```

But when I peeked into db/schema.rb I saw this instead:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110808161830) do
  create_table "categories", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "parent_id"
    t.string  "title", :null => false
  end
  add_index "categories", ["title"], :name => "ix_categories_root_title", :unique => true
end
```

Which obviously isn't the same thing and incorrect.  Is there anyway to force schema.rb to create the same index?  I'm using postresql with Rails 3.1 pre.

Answer (score 3):

iafonov was correct when he said to enable this config option in your application.rb file:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

However, simply enabling this feature does not work as expected. It will not automatically generate a `schema.sql` file. Instead you can use `rake db:structure:dump` which will create a `structure.sql` file. Then you can load it with `rake db:structure:load`

There's a nice explanation here: [schema.sql not creating even after setting schema_format = :sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698467/schema-sql-not-creating-even-after-setting-schema-format-sql)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact reason of your problem, but you can definitely store your index if you'll store your schema in sql

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Btw: which db do you use? Actually this is more like be problem of db driver than problem of rails.

Comment: i'm on rails 3.1 pre with postgresql

Comment: Rails supports only basic set of features of database engines, so the only solution is to dump your schema in sql. The only drawback is loosing readable schema but you'll definitely have all your advanced indexes in place.

Comment: i'm not able to create the schema in sql even after putting "config.active_record.schema_format = :sql" in application.rb. can someone help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034977/how-to-create-schema-in-sql

Comment: same here, it's still generating a .rb file instead of a .sql file

Comment: i think its rake db:schema:dump to generate the sql version

Comment: nope!
it is rake db:structure:dump (http://oomoo.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/migration-related-rake-commands/)