# How to create schema in sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

As per http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012812/schema-rb-index-different-from-individual-migration-index) I have this in application.rb

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

However, it's still creating db/schema.rb (even after I delete it) and more importantly it's not creating the schema in sql when I run "rake db:migrate".  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  I'm on Rails 3.1 pre.

Answer (score 51):

Well, this could be a rails bug, but you can always generate your db structure with this:

```
rake db:structure:dump
```

This is going to generate an "#{Rails.env}.sql" file for you with your database structure in SQL.

Comment: that works but we wanted the .sql file to be updated (like schema.rb) every time we db:migrate.  at least that's what i thought it's supposed to do according to the documentation.  else there's no point in doing "config.active_record.schema_format = :sql" since we can "db:structure:dump" manually anytime no?

Comment: Yes, you'd expect that switching to :sql wouldn't break all the rake support infrastructure for tests - and it seems like a patch to do that was committed several years ago:

    https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/715

but that's not the behavior I'm seeing in Rails 3.2 - It's seeming like the extensive reworking of rake tasks outlined here:

    http://pivotallabs.com/using-mysql-foreign-keys-procedures-and-triggers-with-rails/

is still necessary . . . but maybe I'm missing something?