# rails migration: postgresql for md5 of random string as default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

Rails 3 + postgresql

I want to have a sha of a random string for a default value of a column.

So, in my migration I have:

`t.string :uniqueid, default: md5(random()::text)`

However i can not get this to actually produce anything, I've used backticks, quotes,etc. From examples that I've seen it seems like that pg function only works in a `SELECT` statement.

Is that accurate? Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to look at the generated SQL, because the md5(...) call is perfectly valid as a DEFAULT clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note**: You probably want to look at [brcebn's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60724518/479863) answer if you're using a more recent version of Rails.

---

Rails will try to interpret this:

```
t.string :uniqueid, default: md5(random()::text)
```

as Ruby code and `:default => md5(...)` doesn't mean anything in Ruby. If you quote it, then Rails will think it is a string and make the default value for `uniqueid` the string `'md5(random()::text)'` and that's not going to help.

If you want to use a function call in a column default, you can do the [`alter table`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) by hand:

```
connection.execute(%q{
    alter table your_table alter column uniqueid set default md5(random()::text)
})
```

That will get you the default you want in the database but you might notice that there's no mention of the new default in your `schema.rb`. If you want a usable schema then you'll have to use an [SQL schema instead by putting this in your `application.rb`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4698467/479863):

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Then delete your `schema.rb` and use `structure.sql` instead. Note that SQL schema dumps were broken until 3.2 and there are schema loading problems in various Rails versions (but you can always `psql < structure.sql` your way around that). On the upside, SQL schema dumps will keep track of fancy things real foreign keys, check constraints, triggers, ...

BTW, if you really want SHA then you'll want to look at the [`digest` function from `pgcrypto`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html).

Comment: the connection.execute(...) is that something you would do in the pg console?

Comment: @cbrulak: No, you can do that right inside your migration's `def up` or `def down` methods. You just need to bypass all the Rails stuff and talk straight to the database, that's what `connection.execute` does.

Comment: Okay, that worked. However, when new rows are created the default is still null. Any pointes on that issue?

Comment: @cbrulak: *swearing* ActiveRecord. ActiveRecord doesn't understand the default value it sees in the database and decides to throw a NULL in there instead, see my updated answer for further musings on this. Basically you're stuck with a `before_create` hook to compute the column default in Ruby.

Comment: okay, thanks a lot for you help. I ended up doing that but with the secure random library.

Comment: @cbrulak: There's a more thorough overview of the default value handling [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15239014/479863) if you're interested.

Answer (score 7):

You can also do

```rb
t.string :token, default: -> { "md5((random())::text)" }, null: false
```

**Edit :** Even if this generates a random string with 32 digits, it does not mean it's unique. I thought so but I just had a unique index error.

Comment: This should be the best answer!

Comment: Thanks @KazuyaGosho, I guess it was not existing in Rails 3, 7 years ago. 

Comment: AFAIK this became an option in Rails5. Does this survive through `db/schema.rb`? I always end up switching to `structure.sql` for other things so I don't know.

Comment: I always switch to `structure.sql` too. Si I don't know. But 100% sure it's not unique. It's extremely rare to have twice the same string but it can happen.

Comment: this indeed survives in `schema.rb` if you are on rail5+ version this is definitely the answer